# Bad access error while invoking [playerFactory play] method

Tags: ios, deezer

After a setting all the parameters for the player factory `init`, prepared the player for a preview, I know that my player is initialized by the player state (1). Also, the buffer callback prints out some numbers.

But when I try to call the `play` method, it gives a bad access error about the `[RealPLayer BufferFlushed]`.

To me it seems like a null reference problem, but the player factory class is a singleton and I've declared it in the `init`.

What could it be?

player init

```
    - (id)init {
        if (self = [super init]) {
            deezerPlayer = [PlayerFactory createPlayerWithNetworkType:NetWork_WIFI_AND_3G
                                              andBufferProgressInterval:50.f];
            [deezerPlayer setPlayerDelegate:self];
            [deezerPlayer setBufferDelegate:self];
        }
        return self;
    }
```

this is the prepare for preview called from another class with the url and id needed

```
    - (void) initPlayerForPreviewWithUrl:(NSString *)url andTrackId:(NSString *)trackId{
        NSLog(@"INIT PLAYER WITH LINK: %@ AND ID: %@",url,trackId);
        [deezerPlayer preparePlayerForPreviewWithURL:url trackID:trackId andDeezerConnect:[[deezerClass deezerSession] deezerConnect]];

    }
```

after that i call the play method from the same other class

```
 

    - (void)play {

        [deezerPlayer play];

    }
```

at this point, it gives the error

this is the invoking class

```
    - (void)setTheData{
            [[playerController currentPlayer] initPlayerForPreviewWithUrl:sop.currentSongLink andTrackId:sop.currentSongId];


    }



    - (IBAction)togglePlayPause:(id)sender
    {
        if(playPause.selected) {
                [[playerController currentPlayer] pause];
                [playPause setSelected:NO];
            }
        } else {
                [[playerController currentPlayer] play];
                [playPause setSelected:YES];


        }

    }
```

Note that current player istances of player controller is The deezerplayer in The other class

Comment: Please post your relevant code.  It's impossible for us to guess.

Comment: my fault! from the api request i retrieve the wrong link; so the player request was giving a bad access error for the unknown format.

Answer (score 0):

If you give, wrong song "id" - "streamId" match for the player you get that EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Also note that, if you try to play a song which is indicated as "readable = 0" in the API's JSON response, you may get the same error. I hope Deezer will fix this crash and give an appropriate error message.